# Can I (or Should I) use NSFetchedResultsController for One Table Section?

Tags: ios

I have one section of a table which will display an initial set of comments, and then as new comments are entered and merged into core data, it will display those as well. I could simply tack all the new comments onto the end of the current array using a standard fetch, but I would also like to handle any potential comments that were added in the meantime, and may be mixed into the sort order of the current comments.

I was trying to decide how easiest to do all of this with NSMutableOrderedSet, but really nsfrc already does everything I need, except it works with multiple sections.

Is it wise to try and shoe-horn that in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Core Data, `NSFetchedResultsController` should probably be used for *all* your table views which display core data entities. Even those which are not updating in the background.

In this case you do have things being merged in the background, so `NSFetchedResultsController` is the logical and correct choice.

Comment: I almost always do, but most of the time it's involving a table that is ENTIRELY core data. When I have a table that is say, half static, or one section is one entity, one is another, is that still a standard use case for NSFRC or no? That's my main question.

Comment: I don't see a problem with doing that. As long as you hook everything together correctly, it's fine to source one section from an NSFRC and another from static data.